# Jquery on click function only works for the first row of data.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is auto-generated with data from the database and created using jquery. This is created using the following tr variable which is appended to the main tbody : Below is my code :

```
var list = " <tr id='order_no_tr'><td id='order_no_td" + item.documentno + "'>" + item.documentno + "</td><td>" + item.progressstatus + "</td><td>" + newDate + "</td>\n\
                                <td><button type='button' id='cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' class='btn btn-default btn-sm cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' >Confirm Received</button>\n\
        <input type='hidden' name='order_no_txt' id='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + "' value='" + item.c_order_id + "' class='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + " btn btn-primary'/>\n\
        </td></tr>";
$("#order_no_tbody").append(list);
$("#order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```

Now I have an issue with the on click function, it only works with the first row of the  generated table. How can I make the  onclcick function to work with all the  entries of the onclick function ? Below is the  onclcick function which relies on the  tr id to get the  confirmed order id.

```
$("#order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document.Body).on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```

now click event work for all .cnfrmd_rcvd. Currnetly you are binding click event with #order_no_t

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that id can only match one element, so when you do you call $("#order_no_tr") it will only bind the click event to the first matched tr with that id. Switch it to a class instead and bind to that:

```
$(".order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd", function(ev) { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are create rows dynamically, you should use event delegation to handle event:

```
   $('#order_no_tbody').on('click',".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id,function(){
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);

   })//if #order_no_tbody is not created by js
```

your code didn't work because you were trying to attach event handler to element doesn't exist yet.  using event delegation allow you to attach event handler to its parent element that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same id for more than one element in a page. If you do, the browser will consider only the first element. Use class instead of ID. Your code should be

```
var list = " <tr class='order_no_tr'><td id='order_no_td" + item.documentno + "'>" + item.documentno + "</td><td>" + item.progressstatus + "</td><td>" + newDate + "</td>\n\
                                <td><button type='button' id='cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' class='btn btn-default btn-sm cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' >Confirm Received</button>\n\
        <input type='hidden' name='order_no_txt' id='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + "' value='" + item.c_order_id + "' class='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + " btn btn-primary'/>\n\
        </td></tr>";
$("#order_no_tbody").append(list);
$(".order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find problem that you are searching click event in ID `#order_no_tr` and this ID is for first row of yours table that the reason it working on first row only.

Other Idea is using Class for every Row

So code could be like

```
var list = " <tr class='order_no_tr'><td id='order_no_td" + item.documentno + "'>" + item.documentno + "</td><td>" + item.progressstatus + "</td><td>" + newDate + "</td>\n\
                                <td><button type='button' id='cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' class='btn btn-default btn-sm cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id + "' >Confirm Received</button>\n\
        <input type='hidden' name='order_no_txt' id='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + "' value='" + item.c_order_id + "' class='order_no_txt" + item.c_order_id + " btn btn-primary'/>\n\
        </td></tr>";
$(".order_no_tbody").append(list);
$(".order_no_tr").on("click", ".cnfrmd_rcvd" + item.c_order_id, function() {
    var order_no = this.value;
    alert(order_no);
});
```